# How do I change 'Paste' shortcut for Yakuake?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I wish to remap paste to control + v on Yakuake.

I have already remapped the key in Konsole but Yakuake seems like its only sharing profile keybinding. (Found in Settings - Edit current profile - Shortcut tab) instead of 'Configure shortcuts' option.

How can modify paste key on Yakuake?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found is by context menu in a console(right click), then right click on "Paste" menu item -> Configure shortcut...

The only issue is this setting is persisted only for current session.

Answer (score 0):

There is non-obvious options|preference there under hotkey `Ctrl+Alt+,` ... bruteforced this xD